# create folder according to input field in php

Tags: php, input

in my code project, I am trying to name a folder using an input field(what you type in input field becomes the folders name)so far, I have tried using js variables in `<?php mkdir("test"); ?>`but it dosent work any suggestions?
this is what I have so far:

```html
<?php
   $foldername = ["folder"];
   $structure = 'communities/'.$foldername;

   if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true)) {
      die('Failed to create folders...');
   }
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="folder">
 <input type="submit" value="create">
</form>
```

Comment: Past a relevant piece of code please.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Create or rename a folder?

Comment: Make your HTML form post tge data to the php page and then read it with `$POST["folder"]`

Comment: venturing to dangerous realms?

Comment: I want to create a folder with the name typed into the input

Comment: @Amessihel I have edited my answer with what I have tried

Comment: Creates a directory with a name entered by a user is dangerous.

Comment: `$foldername = ["folder"];` - it's an array :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php you can create folder easily like this.

```
   <?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']){
      $foldername = $_POST['foldername'];
       $structure = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$foldername;

      if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true)) {
        die('Failed to create folders...');
      }
   }
   ?>

<form method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" name="foldername">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Folder">
</form>
```

Comment: i want the user to have an input and a submit button, so they can decide the name of the folder

Comment: the + should be a ., otherwise `$structure` is set to 0

Comment: @parseguy you can submit form and take value in $foldername variable in php

Comment: What if same folder name is entered ?

Answer (score 1):

You must first create your HTML code `<input type="text" name="folder">` then you most use `$_POST["folder"]` and put it into a variable then `mkdir($var);`

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST["folder"])) mkdir($_POST["folder"]);
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="folder">
</form>
```

Comment: `mkdir($_POST["folder"])` is the worst idea I have seen in a long time. at-least prefix with some known folder and use basic sensitization on the input.